# how to search between 2 dates and times in access?

Tags: ms-access-2007

i have in my access fields `MyDate` and `myTime`.

MyDate in format: `16/09/2010 00:00:00`

MyTime in format: `16/09/2010 04:27:00`

i need to search between `date 01/01/2010 and time 12:50:00  - and - date 12/11/2010 time 01:34:00`

which  query i need to write  ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delimiter in Access is hash (#). I hope that you are using a date-time fields, and not two separate fields (columns).

```
SELECT MyDate
FROM tbl
WHERE MyDate Between #2/5/2006 14:7:0# And #11/18/2006 17:28:15#
```

You will find additional notes here on date formats (ANSI, US) and concatenating date & time:

[Error when inserting a record into MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724015/i-got-error-in-insert-to-database-access/3725449#3725449) 
[MS Access 2007: date query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695144/help-with-access-date-query/3696278#3696278)