# Error message that "Either EOF or BOF is true, or the current record has been deleted"

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have written the bellow code to import data from an Access table to Excel, but I am getting an error message at `rs.MoveFirst` reading:

> Either EOF or BOF is true, or the current record has been deleted

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ws As Excel.Application
Dim strSQL As String
Dim i As Long

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM salebill where date >= " & _
sale.fromdate.Value & "  And  date <= " & sale.todate.Value & ""

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=D:\Payroll Soft\Acess\Mobile Shop.mdb;"
    .Open
End With

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open strSQL, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTableDirect

rs.MoveFirst
MsgBox (rs.RecordCount & " Rows Generated")

''Code to Export Data to Export''

Set ws = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ws.Workbooks.Add
ws.range("a3").Select
ws.Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    ws.ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
Next
ws.range("a4").Select
Do Until rs.EOF
    For i = 0 To`enter code here` rs.Fields.Count - 1
        ws.ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = rs.Fields(i).Value
    Next
    ws.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    rs.MoveNext`enter code here`
Loop
rs.Close
```

Comment: Which line is throwing this error?

Comment: rs.moveFirst.......................Error is here

Comment: then the recordset is either empty or already at `BOF`.  You should test for `EOF` and `BOF` before trying to access the recordset.

Comment: Can you please let me know how can i test for EOF and BOF

Comment: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-29.html#Move_With_No_Records

Comment: Your query returns no records.  You need to revise the query so that it returns the records you want.  Suggest you first inspect the `SELECT` statement your code builds by including `Debug.Print strSQL` on the line before `Set cn ...`, run the code, and then examine the statement text in the Immediate window.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test for `EOF` before you trying to use the recordset.

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ws As Excel.Application
Dim strSQL As String
Dim i As Long

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM salebill where date Between #" & _
    sale.fromdate.Value & "#  And #" & sale.todate.Value & "#"


Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=D:\Payroll Soft\Acess\Mobile Shop.mdb;"
    .Open
End With

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open strSQL, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTableDirect

If Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    MsgBox (rs.RecordCount & " Rows Generated")

    ''Code to Export Data to Export''

    Set ws = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ws.Workbooks.Add
    ws.range("a3").Select
    ws.Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        ws.ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next
    ws.range("a4").Select
    Do Until rs.EOF
        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            ws.ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = rs.Fields(i).Value
        Next
        ws.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    If (rs.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen Then rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

End If

If (cn.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen Then cn.Close
Set cn= Nothing
```

Comment: sir i have made necessary changes as per your suggestion but not working.But when i changed my strSQL query to "Select * from salebill" it works great.So i think issue may be in strSQL query. Can you help me how to pass the SQL query.

Comment: What do you mean by "pass the SQL query"? If you mean add the where between 2 dates look at the answer again I have updated it.

Comment: More on that can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725177/how-to-search-between-2-dates-and-times-in-access

Comment: Sir thank you so much for your valuable time...Today i tried your code and found that query not filtering the data between two dates and process entire data at once.