# Date Filtering in Ms Access Query (Interesting)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Its look like the sample but I can't find what this is?

Here are what i want final result =>

[image]

Here is my query=>

```
 Select 
a.staffname,
a.staffno,
a.cntname 
From [Clisys] a 
where 
CDate([a.acdate]) <= #02/08/2018# and  
CntNo='H0128C' and 
[a.JobCode] like '1**/2018' and 
[a.acdate] is Not Null
```

But problem is when i select like that, I get nothing. But when i change where cause like that=>

```
 where 
    CDate([a.acdate]) <= #02/08/2019# and  
    CntNo='H0128C' and 
    [a.JobCode] like '1**/2018' and 
    [a.acdate] is Not Null
```

I get what i want.But why if i select with 2018 is not working?

Comment: What is the data type of that `AcDate` column?  If it's `Date/Time`, why are you using `CDate` to convert it to the type it already is?  If it's not and you have control of the database schema, you should change it so that it is.  If you don't have control of the schema then I guess you're stuck with what you have but, in case you're not already, you should be aware that such a database design is bad and you should avoid doing such things yourself in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Always handle dates as dates, not strings, not numbers, no exceptions.

And when you write SQL, use the correct syntax. The text expression for a date value must be like mm/dd/yyyy or yyyy/mm/dd.

You did use dd/mm/yyyy, thus your date was read as 2018-02-08. So use:

```
CDate([a.acdate]) <= #2018/08/02#
```

and your query will run as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I got an idea from this answer [Once again, year, month, day is
 better.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3696278/9304307) So I changed my date format to 2018/08/02 and this is
 work!.

> The default Access SQL date format, regardless of locale, is
>   mm/dd/yyyy. If you use an invalid date format, it will 'helpfully' try
>   to convert that to a valid date for you.
>
> So, if you use '30/09/2008', it will recognize you're using
>   dd/mm/yyyy, and convert it appropriately. However, a value like
>   '10/01/2008' is a valid mm/dd/yyyy value to begin with, so it will not
>   be converted, and stored incorrectly in case you actually meant
>   dd/mm/yyyy....
>
> The solution is to always convert your date values to a mm/dd/yyyy
>   string prior to using them in Access SQL statements. You have to be a
>   bit careful here, as using VBA date format masks may not work entirely
>   as you'd expect on non-US locales (e.g. 'helpfully' interpreting
>   "mm/dd/yyyy" as "the localized short date format"), so please test
>   carefully using your particular Access/VBA version.

Comment: How are you getting that date value into the SQL code in the first place?  If it's not hard-coded then you should be using a parameter anyway, in which case format is completely irrelevant.